# how to load php action page instead of php file in javascript?

Tags: php, html, ajax

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function showUser(str) {
                if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else {
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                        }
                    };
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            }
        </script>
}
</script>
```

Code is working 100% but my problem is in script in place of getuser.php i want to use action for example "action=records" . what should i change

Comment: You can add that as another parameter in your url - `xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str+"&action=records",true);`

Comment: can u help me what should i use